# Are CW complexes closed under homotopy colimits?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the category of topological spaces homotopy equivalent (in the strong sense) to CW complexes. Is this category closed under arbitrary homotopy colimits? how about filtered homotopy colimits?

By homotopy colimit I mean the standard definition given by simplicial replacement. For example check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_colimit#Construction_of_colimits_with_simplicial_replacements).

The simplest case is when the filtered category is just a directed category and colimit becomes direct homotopy limit, which is given by the mapping telescope construction.

My first intuition was that since each space is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex and each map between CW complex is homotopy equivalent to a cellular map, replacing these in the simplicial replacement should not change the homotopy type. By doing so it seems that gluing bunch of CW complexes along cellular maps becomes another CW complex. But now I am not sure, it seems doing so preserves the weak homotopy type not the homotopy type.

Comment: What definition of "homotopy colimit" are you using?

Comment: @EricWofsey The one given by mapping telescopes, i.e. first thicken each space by multiplication by an interval, then the transition maps turn into cofibrations. Then we glue these. I think this is the standard definition given for example in Dugger's notes.

Comment: It's pretty easy to see that the category is not closed under homotopy *limits*.

Answer (score 1):

For a subcategory $C \subset \operatorname{Top}$, let $W$ denote the subcategory of weak equivalences of spaces. Let $\operatorname{CW}$ denote the full subcategory of CW complexes and let $\operatorname{CW}^h$ denote the full subcategory of spaces homotopy equivalent to CW complexes. The relative category $(\operatorname{Top},W)$ is equivalent to the relative category $(\operatorname{CW},W)$ as a result of the CW approximation theorem. This is an equivalence in the sense that the simplicial localizations of either relative category are equivalent. For the same reason, $(\operatorname{CW}^h,W)$ is equivalent to $(CW,W)$.

Since homotopy colimits depend only on the simplicial localization, and it is well known that $(\operatorname{Top},W)$ is closed under homotopy colimits, we are done.

Comment: I don't like the appearance of weak equivalences. Does this imply that if I glue bunch of CW complexes given by transition maps after turning them into cofibrations (mapping telescope), is the resulting space homotopy equivalent to a CW complex or weakly homotopy equivalent?